# SimpleTest not being triggered, yet still maxing out the server

Tags: php, simpletest

I'm sharing a simple PHP MVC framework with some students. As part of the framework, it includes SimpleTest in it's core/vendors/.

A handful of the students are getting notices from their shared hosts that their accounts are being shut down because of CPU abuse from the detached_test.php within SimpleTest:

```
We regret to inform you that your account has been suspended for the following reason:
CPU / processes abuse via
joesmith 14425 12668 0 00:07 ?        00:00:00 /usr/bin/php
/home/joesmith/public_html/dwa/core/vendors/simpletest/test/detached_test.php
```

Edit: There's also a report of it maxing out on simpletest/test/failing_test.php.

What I can't figure out is **what would even be triggering these scripts** - nothing the users is doing is actually invoking SimpleTest. It just ships with the framework for us to user later on.

Furthermore, when I search the contents of the SimpleTest folder, none of the other scripts ever invoke detached_test.php - so it seems as if this script is being directly triggered.

I found a similar report (unresolved) of this from a WordPress plugin for Pinterest that is using SimpleTest as well:
http://wordpress.org/support/topic/plugin-pinterest-pinboard-widget-crashed-my-site

Is SimpleTest being targeted by bots?

Comment: if it invoked directly you should check webserver logs, if it is apache, add rule to .htaccess that prevent that script to be triggered directly

Comment: Not seeing it in apache access log so assuming it's not being triggered from http. Is there a way to lock down scripts from being executed via cl?

Comment: idk, add exit to very begining of the script :)

Comment: Hah :) Just got word it's maxing out on a different script now too, so afraid plugging the hole on a script by script basis is no longer viable.

Comment: I know you probably don't wanna hear it, but phpunit would likely make way more sense ...

Comment: Because... SimpleTest is known for problems like this and phpunit isn't? Or just because you / others think the latter is a better testing platform. If the latter, totally irrelevant suggestion to the specific problem at hand! :)

Comment: Do you have access to the webserver logs? This would actually show you what/who triggered the scripts.